# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DBNet

Tags: pytorch, ocr, fastapi

I have trained a doctr detection model and save it checkpoint but while running it in Fastapi application it giving error

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DBNet
```

Code

```
import os
os.environ["USE_TORCH"] = "1"
import torch
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor, db_resnet50
from doctr.file_utils import is_tf_available, is_torch_available
print(f"TF available: {is_tf_available()}, PyTorch available: {is_torch_available()}")


class DoctrTrainInference:
    def __init__(self,det_model_path=None):
        model = db_resnet50(pretrained=False)
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(det_model_path, map_location= "cpu"))
        self.predictor = ocr_predictor(det_arch=model, pretrained=True)
            
    def __call__(self):
        return self.predictor
```

Model is trained in pytorch

I have tried to run in containerized environment still getting same error

Comment: Is there any other error lines after ? Such as "Unexpected keys ..." or "Missing keys ..." ? That could help us knowing what is the issue